# How to define a function with a matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to define a  two variables function `g` so that `g(x,y)` be a 2*2 matrix. To do this, I define `g(x,y)=[1,1;x,y]` but when I put `g(1,1)` I don't get any answer. How can I evaluate to `g`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that different from [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711138/3372061), but perhaps an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) would meet your needs:

```matlab
>> g = @(x,y)[1,1;x,y];
>> g(5,6)
ans =
     1     1
     5     6
```

Alternatively, if you want `g` to accept only one input (i.e. a 2-element vector, instead of two scalars), you could do:

```matlab
g = @(x)[1,1;x(1),x(2)];
% or
g = @(x)[1,1;x(:).'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's true.

Comment: If I have a function h(x,y) in advance and now I want define to define a new function g(x,y) by h(x,y), can I write g=@(x,y)h(x,y)?

Comment: @M.Ramana what happened when you tried it? You could probably just write `g = @h` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The code `g(x,y)=[1,1;x,y]` itself will not do anything. I assume that your expect result will be `g=[1,1,1,1]`? Therefore you should do as follow:

```
g=g_func(1,1);
disp(g)

function g=g_func(x,y)
g=[1,1;x,y];
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code does not work. Actually I have a matrix with 2 variables as a result of something. Now, I want to evaluate to that matrix. How do I do that? For example, let [1,1;x,y] be a matrix with x,y two variables. How can I evaluate to this matrix with (for example) x=5 ,y=6?

Comment: You can just use `g=g_func(x,y)` and you will have `g=[1,1,5,6]`.